# Mail batching with Gmail fails with SMTP, succeeds with Google API

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, jakarta-mail, google-authentication, completable-future

I have a Node.js batch that processes a list of users, and makes API calls to a Java backend for every user. The Node.js batch and the Java backend both send mails to users with a G-Suite account.

No problem for Node.js, all of the mails succeed. Concerning Java, after a particular amount of mails sent, the following mails fail with the following message:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication
failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:
334
eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
;   nested exception is:    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:
OAUTH2 asked for more   at
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:424)
at
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
```

Which once Base64 decoded gives:

> {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}

Here are some details of my implementations.

```
@Service
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Value("${fr.app.email.service-account}")
    private String serviceAccount;

    @Value("${fr.app.email.scope}")
    private String scope;

    private Credential creds;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy à HH:mm");

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Void> sendSimpleMail(String email, String subject, String text) throws Exception {

        if(creds == null) {
            final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
            final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
            final URL URL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("MyApp-d8a5d9785c54.p12");

            creds = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccount)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(URL.getFile()))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(scope))
                .setServiceAccountUser(((JavaMailSenderImpl)javaMailSender).getUsername())
                .build();
        }

        if(creds.getExpiresInSeconds() != null && creds.getExpiresInSeconds() < 0 || creds.getAccessToken() == null) {
            creds.refreshToken();
        }

        try {

            ((JavaMailSenderImpl)javaMailSender).setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            ((JavaMailSenderImpl)javaMailSender).setPassword(creds.getAccessToken());
            Message message = new MimeMessage(((JavaMailSenderImpl)javaMailSender).getSession());
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(((JavaMailSenderImpl)javaMailSender).getUsername()));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

            javaMailSender.send((MimeMessage)message);

            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the working Node.js implementation:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

// configure a JWT auth client
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    config.appServiceAccount,
    config.googleKeyFile,
    null,
    [config.googleScope],
    config.appMail
);

logger.info('Gmail client created!');

const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: jwtClient });

function sendMail(gmail, jwtClient, to, subject, message) {

    let headers = {
        "To": to,
        "Subject": subject,
        "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    }

    let email = '';
    for (var header in headers)
        email += header += ": " + headers[header] + "\r\n";

    email += "\r\n" + message;

    return gmail.users.messages.send({
        auth: jwtClient,
        userId: config.appMail,
        requestBody: {
            raw: btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
        }
    });
}
```

I've got some more details about the error thanks to the `mail.debug=true` configuration key: the first 80 messages produce the following output:

```
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com,
user=contact@example.com, password=<non-null> DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to
authenticate using mechanisms: XOAUTH2 DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism
XOAUTH2 AUTH XOAUTH2 <access_token>
235 2.7.0 Accepted
```

The following messages produce the output:

```
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com,
user=contact@example.com, password=<non-null> DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to
authenticate using mechanisms: XOAUTH2 DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism
XOAUTH2 AUTH XOAUTH2 <exact same access_token>
334
eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH XOAUTH2 failed, THROW:
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: OAUTH2 asked for more
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$OAuth2Authenticator.doAuth(SMTPTransport.java:1095)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:909)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:843)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:748)
```

Regarding [the Node.js client implementation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/c87b6f7b555472f5c2ec187216712c4ed9aac333/src/apis/gmail/v1.ts#L1502), the main difference is that Node.js doesn't seem to use SMTP, but calls an API instead.

I've read [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491#sendinglimitsforrelay) that there are specific limitations for SMTP but I can't figure out which limitation I have reached because the error message is very unclear (DDoS, messages per 10 minutes, ...).

Comment: Your OAUTH2 access token probably expired and needs to be refreshed.

Comment: @BillShannon my implementation is supposed to refresh the token when needed. Do you see anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Make sure it's refreshing when you think it should.  You have an expression that uses "&&" and "||" and no parentheses, is it really doing what you expect?

Comment: @BillShannon I will investigate but if the problem comes from the token, do you explain why it happens only when sending many mails at a time? Is there some "bean expiration" when it idles that explains this behavior?

Comment: Token expiration is based on time.  Presumably how many messages you send determines the amount of time taken.  But clearly I'm just guessing about token expiration, you need to do some debugging.